# How do I manually control the opacity of menus?

Tags: menu, styles, codenameone

My codename1 application's menus are appearing in a semi-transparent state.
How can I change that to fully opaque?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you left the `Graphics` you worked with in the same state you got it. So if you manipulate the alpha of the core graphics restore it to the original value.

The same is true for the translate values etc.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.addComponent(new ComboBox<String>("Hi", "World", "Is", "This", "Opaque"));
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, not the answer I am looking for.  I show a combobox and all thr list items are transparent.  I never see or use a Graphics.

Comment: What styles did you use? Did you override any UIID or default theme?

Comment: completely default.  I'm ignoring styles except for setting fonts and colors.  My main window classes had to be made opague.

Comment: Which theme did you pick when you created the app? The blue theme?

Comment: Whichever one is the default.  The banner along the top is green.

Comment: I found I could change the default by editing the ComboxList item in the theme, but there's still a border component that's grey and transparent, and my question was how can I change it at runtime, potentially for just one menu.

Comment: It was totally unclear that this was the question from the initial one sentence! It's easier to change it from the theme where it has the UIID `ComboBoxPopup`. If you wish to change it from the code you can do so when by overriding `protected Dialog createPopupDialog(List<T> l)` and setting the style for the returned dialog.